# How to concatenate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

My database doesn't have a specific column so I created a column in my query by switch. What I need is to concatenate this column with another column in the database:

```
select 
    certificateDuration ,
   'DurationType' = case
                      when certificateDurationType = 0 then 'Day' 
                      when certificateDurationType = 1 then 'Month'
                      when certificateDurationType = 2 then 'Year'
                    end
from 
    Scientific_Certification
```

Comment: `||` is the concatenation operator in SQL: `columnA || columnB` will concatenate the value of `columnB` to the end of the value of `columnA`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: that is the concatenation operator in **ORACLE** - but ***NOT*** in (Microsoft) SQL Server!

Comment: @marc_s To be fair, `||` is the ANSI standard rather than an Oracle dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate strings in SQL Server you can simply use the [+ operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).
Note that if one of the substrings is null then the entire concatenated string will become null as well. therefor, use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) if you need a result even if one substring is null.

```
select certificateDuration,
       ' DurationType = '+ 
       COALESCE(case
                     when certificateDurationType = 0 then 'Day' 
                     when certificateDurationType = 1 then 'Month'
                     when certificateDurationType = 2 then 'Year'
                     end, '') As DurationType 
from Scientific_Certification
```

**Note:** I've used coalesce on your case clause since you have no default behavior (specified by `else`). this means that if `certificateDurationType` is not 0, 1 or 2 the case statement will return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to try `+` operator or `CONCAT` function

1. `+` for all SQL Server versions

   ```
   DurationType = ' + 'some text'
   ```
2. `CONCAT` for SQL Server 2012 +

   ```
   CONCAT('DurationType = ', 'some text')
   ```

Your query should be something  like this

```
SELECT certificateDuration
       ,'DurationType = ' + 
       CASE certificateDurationType
           WHEN 0 THEN 'Day'
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Month'
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Year'
       END
FROM Scientific_Certification
```

Answer (score 0):

you must try this SQL query to contact the columns. Here I concat three columns of user table named (name_first, name_middle, name_last) and got the result into a single column named FULLNAME.

[image: Code for SQL query]

Here is the image of result

[image: Result]