# CONCAT columns with Laravel 5 eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Consider me as laravel beginner

The goal is: I have two colums, now I need the `id` to be prefixed with the `component name` of same row in the table.

For Example (Working)... I have Mysql like

```
SELECT CONCAT(components.name," ", components.id) AS ID
FROM   `components`
```

And output is

> ID

```
|TestComp 40  |
 -------------
|component 41 |
 -------------
|test 42      |
```

I need the same in laravel eloquent way, as here Component is Model name. So i tried something like

```
$comp=Component::select("CONCAT('name','id') AS ID")->get()
```

but it doesn't work.
I think because the  syntax is wrong.
Kindly help me with the correct syntax. Using `laravel` `Models`.

Note: I made the above query, referring this as which available on internet.

```
User::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(last_name, first_name) AS full_name'))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eloquent, but from my experience with ORM frameworks, you need no do this, because you can do something like this: `$entity = $model->getById(1);echo $entity->getLastName().$entity->getFirstName();` It can be look like overhead, but ORM frameworks is always overhead.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to wrap your query in `DB::raw`:

```
$comp = Component::select(DB::raw("CONCAT('name','id') AS ID"))->get()
```

Also, note because you are doing your query like this, your model might behave differently, because this select removes all other fields from the select statement.
So you can't read the other fields from your model without a new query. So ONLY use this for READING data and not MODIFYING data.

Also, to make it in a nice list, I suggest you modify your query to:

```
$comp = Component::select(DB::raw("CONCAT('name','id') AS display_name"),'id')->get()->pluck('display_name','id');
// dump output to see how it looks.
dd($comp);// array key should be the arrray index, the value the concatted value.
```

Comment: thx. its because i have a drop down. it will show the combined list from two table. i have used union query. before that i planed to prefix the items.. so that i could differentiate which is from component and product table. for example  if user select 5 item that belongs to product and 2 items that belongs to component table. then i can take the items that prefixed with p..so i will get that 5 items.. then i can remove that prefix while saving. and also to note while displaying for user its value will be hidden.. so the user only see the items not its values and also i save by removing prefix

Comment: $comp = Component::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(name,id) AS display_name"),'id')->get()->pluck('display_name','id');
// dump output to see how it looks.
dd($comp);// array key should be the arrray index, the value the concatted value.

This works for me with modify

Comment: It is only showing name & id instead showing actual name & id.
I did like this.

`$comp = Component::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(name,id) AS ID"))->get()`

Comment: @RajeshKChaudhary might be your database engine. The moment you start working with raw sql you have to be mindful of your database systems syntax.

Comment: @Tschallacka In your example,  *name* column name must be pass in the select function then we can use in the CONCAT function other wise it provide blank value.
`$comp = Component::select(DB::raw("CONCAT('name','id') AS display_name"),'id','name')->get()->pluck('display_name','id');`

Comment: @BhavinThummar That should not be the case since it's a raw query. What is the output of the toSql() in your own code without the name field added in the select? Something might have changed in laravel versions, or your query has a conflict.

Comment: @Tschallacka Laravel version is 8.

Answer (score 14):

I came to this post for answers myself. The only problem for me is that the answer didn't really work for my situation. I have numerous table relationships setup and I needed one of the child objects to have a concatenated field. The `DB::raw` solution was too messy for me. I kept searching and found the answer I needed and feel it's an easier solution.

Instead of `DB::raw`, I would suggest trying an [Eloquent Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor). Accessors allow you to retrieve model attributes AND to create new ones that are not created by the original model.

For instance, let's say I have a basic USER_PROFILE table. It contains `id, first_name, last_name`. I have the need to CONCAT the two name attributes to return their user's full name. In the USER_PROFILE Model I created `php artisan make:model UserProfile`, I would place the following:

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{

  /**
   * Get the user's full concatenated name.
   * -- Must postfix the word 'Attribute' to the function name
   *
   * @return string
   */

  public function getFullnameAttribute()
  {
      return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
  }

}
```

From here, when I make any eloquent calls, I now have access to that additional attribute accessor.

```
| id | first_name | last_name |
-------------------------------
| 1  | John       | Doe       |


$user = App\UserProfile::first(); 

$user->first_name;   /** John **/
$user->fullname;    /** John Doe **/
```

I will say that I did run into one issue though. That was trying to create a modified attribute with the same name, like in your example (id, ID). I can modify the id value itself, but because I declared the same name, it appears to only allow access to that field value and no other field.

Others have said they can do it, but I was unable to solve this questions EXACT problem.

Comment: I had to do both the things described in Answer1 as well as answer2 for Laravel 5.8.

Comment: Does this work with eager loading ?

Answer (score 8):

I working on posgresql and mysql:

```
DB::raw('CONCAT(member.last_name, \' \', member.first_name) as full_name')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$text = "other";
$limit = 100
public function get_data($text, $limit)
{
    
    $result = $this->select('titulo', 'codigo', DB::Raw("CONCAT(codigo, ' ', titulo_long) AS text_search"))
                ->where('tipo', '=', 2)
                ->having('text_search', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
    return $result;

}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Here is the example of columns concatenation in Laravel.

I need to search the user by name and I have three columns for the user name (name_first, name_middle, name_last), so I have created a scope in Laravel UserModel which takes **$query** and **user name** as the second parameter.

```
public function scopeFindUserByName($query,$name) {
    // Concat the name columns and then apply search query on full name
    $query->where(DB::raw(
            // REPLACE will remove the double white space with single (As defined)
            "REPLACE(
                /* CONCAT will concat the columns with defined separator */
                CONCAT(
                    /* COALESCE operator will handle NUll values as defined value. */
                    COALESCE(name_first,''),' ',
                    COALESCE(name_middle,''),' ',
                    COALESCE(name_last,'')
                ),
            '  ',' ')"
        ),
    'like', '%' . $name . '%');
}
```

and you can use this scope anywhere you need to search user by his name, like

```
UserModel::findUserByName("Max Begueny");
```

OR

```
$query = UserModel::query();
$query->findUserByName("Max Begueny");
```

To check the result of this SQL query just go through from this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62296860/11834856

Answer (score 2):

this code should work:

```
User::select(\DB::raw('CONCAT(last_name, first_name) AS full_name)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrubbing the Data: Before using Laravel and now, when developing in other languages, I would use CONCAT() on a regular basis.  The answers here work to a degree but there still isn't an elegant way to use CONCAT() in Laravel/Eloquent/Query Builder
 that I have found.

However, I have found that concatenating the cols AFTER returning the results works well for me and is usually very fast - Scrubbing the data - ( unless you have a huge result which should probably be "chunked" anyway for performance purposes ).

```
foreach($resultsArray AS $row){
    $row['fullname'] = trim($row['firstname']).' '.trim($row['lastname']);
}
```

This is a tradeoff of course but, personally, I find it to be much more manageable and doesn't limit my use of Eloquent as intended as well as the Query Builder. ( the above is pseudo code - not tested so tweak as needed )

There are other workarounds as well that don't mess with Eloquent/Query Builder functionality such as creating a concatenated col in the table, in this case full_name - save the full name when the record is inserted/updated. This is not uncommon.