# Concatenate two field into a alias name laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$data = DB::table('tables')
    ->select('orders.order_id', 'users.*')
    ->leftJoin('lists', 'lists.order_id', '=', 'orders.order_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.user_id', '=', 'lists.user_id')
    ->where('users.type', '=', 'admin')
    ->get();

dd($data);
```

getting first_name and last_name how can i group those i.e alias says full_name
fullname => Max jones

Concatenate two field into a alias name laravel

Comment: One option would be to use Eloquent models instead of raw queries and then you can create an accessor for full_name. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used `raw` method laravel  and mysql `concat` method used here

```
DB::raw("CONCAT(`users`.`first_name`,`users`.`last_name`) as full_name")
```

**try**

```
$data = DB::table('tables')
    ->select('orders.order_id', DB::raw("CONCAT(`users`.`first_name`,`users`.`last_name`) as full_name"))
    ->leftJoin('lists', 'lists.order_id', '=', 'orders.order_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.user_id', '=', 'lists.user_id')
    ->where('users.type', '=', 'admin')->get();

dd($data);
```

Comment: $comp = Component::select(DB::raw("CONCAT('name','id') AS ID"))->get()
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42759042/7063286

Answer (score 0):

`DB::raw("CONCAT('name','id') AS ID"))`