# How to use orderBy() with model's method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How can I use orderBy to order by a model's method?

Consider the model User and the method

```
public function fullName() {
    return $this->firstName . $this->lastName;
}
```

I want to do something like orderBy('fullName'). Is this possible? I know I can make equivalent code using Query Builder, but I want to keep my Model methods as they are.

Comment: short answer, no, thats not possible. `orderBy()` will be translated into SQL `Order BY` which it have no idea about your `fullname()`.. as last resort, you may consider [using `DB::raw()` to concat things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42759042/4648586).

Comment: so I'll have to use DB:raw() to rewrite all of my methods

Comment: sadly yes, or you may use denormalization trick instead. create a column named `fullname` and have it assigned every model saving.. oh wait they had [`orderByRaw` on 5.7](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderByRaw) - probably can do something like `->orderByRaw('CONCAT(firstname, lastname)')`, may i know what version of your Laravel?

Comment: I'm using 5.7. I would like to keep my existing methods, but it seems I'll have to code them using DB:raw().

Comment: no, you still have that `orderByRaw` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with this solution:

```
$sorted = User::get()
    ->sortBy('full_name')  //appended attribute
    ->pluck('id')
    ->toArray();

$orderedIds = implode(',', $sorted);

$result = DB::table('user')
    ->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, ".$orderedIds." )"))
    ->paginate(10);
```

I've appended fullName attribute to the model, to be used by sortBy.
With this solution I was able to use orderBy to order by an appended attribute of the model, exactly what I wanted to do. So yes, it is possible. And also I was able to use pagination. Thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a few options here:

1. Create a view in your database, which has the column `fullName`. Then change your model to use the view.
2. Create a computed column fullName so that on insert if will use the values given from firstName and lastName.
3. Use Laravel's Collection class. This class provides a sortBy method which you can use an attributes.

If you go with option 2, first define an attribute:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->firstName . $this->lastName;
}
```

Then using Laravel's Collection:

```
$items = Model::all()->sortBy('FullName');
```

**Note**: The default option for `sortBy` is ascending, so if you wish to sort descending:

```
$items = Model::all()->sortByDesc('FullName');
```

You can read more about accessors here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: I can't use sortBy, because I'm using pagination and Collections don't have pagination.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $personas = Persona::select('*');
    $personas = $personas->addSelect(DB::raw('concat(nombre,\' \',apellido1,\' \',apellido2) as fullname'))
            ->orderBy('fullname', 'ASC')->paginate(K_LINEAS_X_PAGINA);
```

I couldn't make it work without the select('*')