# How to fix Unknown column 'CONCAT' in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Work in the native query but when I turn into laravel code there is some error

I confused because my CONCAT is considered as column

```
$query = DB::table('bonus_produksi')
            ->join('bonus_areas', 'bonus_produksi.area', '=', 'bonus_areas.id')
            ->select('bonus_produksi.area',
                     'CONCAT(\'Rp.\',frupiah(bonus_produksi.besaran)',
                     'bonus_areas.nama_area')->get();
```

> Unknown column 'CONCAT('Rp.',frupiah(bonus_produksi.besaran),',00')'

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42735071/1483629

Comment: if you are using RAW sql in your select function, you need to tell it you are. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below answer

```
$query = DB::table('bonus_produksi')
        ->join('bonus_areas', 'bonus_produksi.area', '=', 'bonus_areas.id')
        ->selectRaw("bonus_produksi.area,
                 CONCAT('Rp.',frupiah(bonus_produksi.besaran),
                 bonus_areas.nama_area")->get();
```

Comment: i try your answer but i get {"draw":1,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":0,"data":[],"error":"Exception Message:\n\nUndefined property: stdClass::$id"}

Comment: you have to add id in your selectRaw string. dont forget to add a comma seperator

Answer (score 2):

### Inform the query builder you are using a RAW statement.

```
$query = DB::table('bonus_produksi')
            ->join('bonus_areas', 'bonus_produksi.area', '=', 'bonus_areas.id')
            ->select('bonus_produksi.area',
                     DB::raw("CONCAT(\'Rp.\',frupiah(bonus_produksi.besaran) as column_name"),
                     'bonus_areas.nama_area')->get();
```

Be sure to also include this at the top:

```
use DB;
```